# WPF Validate Properties of Model Object in View-Model Using IDataErrorInfo

Tags: wpf, vb.net, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I am new to WPF and MVVM and I am trying to do data validation using IDataErrorInfo. Here's the scenario. I have a model called Loan.

**The Model**

```
Public Class Loan
Private _AccountNumber As String

Public Property AccountNumber() As String
    Get
       Return _AccountNumber
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
       _AccountNumber = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

**The View-Model**

```
Public Class LoanViewModel
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo

Private _Loan As New Loan() ' Loan object
Public Property Loan() As Loan
    Get
       Return _Loan
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Loan)
       _Loan = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

**The View**

The data context is set to LoanViewModel and TextBox binds to the properties of the loan object in the View-Model.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Loan.AccountNumber, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

My question is, how should I validate the property (i.e AccountNumber) of the Loan object from my View-Model?

Comment: Instead of directly binding the 'Text' property to the model use an intermediate property in view model. Implement 'IDataErrorInfo' in view model. The validation is fired the moment you raise the property changed event. Only when the validation is passed you should assign the value to the property in model.

Comment: Doing that seems redundant since my application consists of about 20 Models and each model has in excess of 10 properties so I don't want to redefine these properties in the View-Model also. What other alternatives do I have?

Comment: The other alternative would be implementing `IDataErrorInfo` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces in the Model which I personally would not recommend

Comment: That's what I read, data validation should be done from the View-Model. However, most of the examples I came across have data validation done in the Models and I know this is not the right way, so I won't do that. Anyways, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Then you are only left with one choice by implementing intermediate properties in VM. Your current approach has a flaw that the value to the Model property is assigned directly without any verification.